# How many ways can one rearrange the letters in the word ATTENTION such that the first letter is a T but the second one isn't?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The number of arrangements of all letters in the word ATTENTION that can be arranged so that each arrangement begins with a T, and the second letter is not a T is

my work:

There are $9$ letters in the word ATTENTION so that means there are nine spaces
so you would do 
$9!=9\times8\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1=362880$ of arrangements

Is this the correct way to do this problem? If not, how do you do it?

Comment: Your answer is not considering the fact that the first letter has to be a T and the fact that the second letter can't be a T.

Comment: Your answer is also not considering that there are some repeated letters.  The answer of $9!$ is the number of arrangements of `ABCDEFGHI` where all letters are distinct, but the number should clearly be lower than that.  Consider arranging the letters in `AAAAAAAAA`.  There is only one such arrangement, not $9!$.  Swapping the positions of two identical letters doesn't make a "different" word, though your calculations incorrectly assume otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Approach via rule of product.

- Choose the three positions of the $T$'s
- Choose the two positions of the $N$'s from those remaining
- Arrange the remaining letters

Note that when choosing the three positions of the $T$'s, the first position *must* be included and the second position must *not* be included.  So... this is effectively the same as choosing *two* positions from the last *seven* positions.

Note that regardless what choice was made in this first step, although the types of choices change for the later steps the *number* of choices is always the same.

$$\binom{7}{2}\times\binom{6}{2}\times 4!$$

Comment: so the answer is 252? which is the number of arrangements?

Comment: @RanveerMasuta Where did I give you the impression that the answer was $252$?  No.  It is not.  I even gave you the answer above... are you able to read the symbols I used?  Where did $252$ even come from?

Comment: well i did 7/2=3.5 multiply by 6/2=3 multiply by 4!

Comment: @RanveerMasuta $\binom{7}{2}$ is not the same thing as $\dfrac{7}{2}$.  The binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k} = \dfrac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ counts the number of ways of selecting $k$ things from $n$, here we are selecting $2$ positions out of the $7$ positions other than the first or second.

Comment: so howwould i put that in my calculator,becasue thats not how my teacher taught me,do you mind showing me this way

Comment: What calculator?  Most scientific or graphing calculators have a button for the binomial coefficient, sometimes with the label $~_nC_r$... Regardless, this can be done by hand easily... $\binom{7}{2}=\dfrac{7!}{2!5!}=\dfrac{7\times 6}{2} = 21$

Comment: Also... don't rely too heavily on calculators.  It is preferable in many educational settings to *not* simplify your final answers... I would be ten times happier as a teacher seeing $\binom{7}{2}\binom{6}{2}4!$ than I would be seeing $7560$.  It helps to show what the student's thought process was helping allow me to point out *why* a mistake occurs if a student made a mistake, what was wrong with their logic.  If a student just gives a raw number with no thought process, I don't know how or why they got it wrong.  I can give partial credit if not simplified, but often not if simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way to compute it

The first letter need to be a "T": $3$ possibilities

The second letter is not a "T": $6$ possibilities.

The we put the remaining letters, giving
$$3\times6\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1$$
But this number consider the "T"s and the "N"s to be distincts. Since they are not, we need to divide this number by $3\times2\times1$ for the "T"s and $2\times1$ for the "N"s

Final answer:
$$\frac{3\times6\times7\times6\times5\times4\times3\times2\times1}{3\times2\times1\times2\times1}=7560\text{ possibilities}$$